# Updating Heroku gem, on RVM (OSX), has resulted in a LoadError and "broken" heroku gem. What is safest way to fix?

Tags: heroku, rubygems, rvm

I have been using RVM (v1.14.11 & JewelryBox GUI), with OSX 10.6.8, for over a year now without any problems. I have two rubies installed (1.9.2 & 1.9.3), plus various gemsets for each ruby.

Since I just finished migrating my current databases to their new offerings, I figured I may as well update the heroku gem (was 2.14). So I selected, via rvm, my ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails gemset, opened up Terminal, and ran "heroku udpate".

I did not notice any errors during the update, but I tried running a "heroku version", plus various other "heroku" commands, and now receive the following error:

```
/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': no such file to load -- netrc (LoadError)
        from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /Users/me/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/auth.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /Users/me/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/client.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails/gems/heroku-2.14.0/lib/heroku.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails/gems/heroku-2.14.0/bin/heroku:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails/bin/heroku:19:in `load'
        from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails/bin/heroku:19:in `<main>'
```

I notice that there are some references to "1.9.1" in the above, which was the original gemset I had isntalled with rvm, then updated it to "1.9.2". Perhaps this is the cause?

Running "gem environment" gives:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.10
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2011-07-09 patchlevel 290) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-10
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails
     - /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

I do have another gemset (ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails32) which also contains the "heroku" gem, and when I switch to it, using rvm, there is no problem using its "heroku" gem.

Since an rvm/osx installation can sometimes be "temperamental", or at least was in the past,  I could really use some advice on what went wrong, and how I can I **safely** fix the broken gemset.

Thanks.

Comment: Easy: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12064804/115363

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Gem `netrc` is dependency of `heroku`, run `gem install heroku` again to install all dependencies.

Comment: After installing ruby-1.9.2-p320, a new gemset & upgrading to Rails 3.2.10 under RVM, running any Heroku command threw up: dyld: unknown required load command 0x80000022, Trace/BPT trap. Googling suggested this was a Git prob (I'm running OSX 10.5.8), but in the end gem install heroku fixed it. Just sayin'

Answer (score 3):

Remove heroku client if the above solution didn't work, I've solved the same problem with this:

```
rm -rf ~/.heroku/client
```

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug in the updater in some earlier versions.  I would recommend redownloading and reinstalling from https://toolbelt.heroku.com.  After doing that you should have the latest version and update should work as expected as new versions continue to be released.

Comment: I wish I had tried `gem update heroku` as per the [Heroku command docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-command).. but I found those after doing the following (with success): `which heroku` made me recall that I had installed heroku as a gem (`/Users/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@bar/bin/heroku`). So I uninstalled it (`gem uninstall heroku`) and then reinstalled the Heroku command via the [toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/), **with foreman**, but **without git**, as I already have git installed. I now have `heroku-toolbelt/2.32.4 (universal-darwin10.0) ruby/1.8.7 autoupdate`.

Comment: `toolbelt` installs `git`, `heroku`, and `foreman` in `/usr/local/git/bin/git`, `/usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku`, and `/usr/local/foreman/bin/foreman`, respectively. The version of `git` pre-installed on my system (Mountain Lion) is `1.7.10.2` (`/usr/bin/git`), whereas `toolbelt` installs version `1.7.8.4`. The [latest stable git](http://git-scm.com/) is `1.7.12.4` and [brew](http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/) installs `1.7.12.3` (`/usr/local/Cellar/git/1.7.12.3/bin/git`).

Answer (score 0):

`gem install heroku` might not be enough in the event you had the heroku gem within a Gemfile of a specific project.  I ran into this problem, and had to do a `bundle update heroku`.  It just depends on what your project is using, a local gemset, or a global gemset.  Of course, you want to make sure that your Gemfile doesn't have the heroku gem locked at a specific version, otherwise running an update will do nothing.